# Check values between two columns

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, concatenation

I need to do the following steps on two columns -A and B- of my **df** and output the result in C:

```
1) check if value from B is present in A -on row, at any position
2) if present but in another format then remove
3) add value from B in A and output in C



A                          B                C
tshirt for women           TSHIRT           TSHIRT for women 
Zaino Estensibile          SJ Gang          SJ Gang Zaino Estensibile 
Air Optix plus             AIR OPTIX        AIR OPTIX plus
```

Workaround with concatenation between A and B and duplicate removal:

Version1

```
def uniqueList(row):
    words = str(row).split(" ")
    unique = words[0]
    for w in words:
        if w.lower() not in unique.lower() :
            if w.lower()not in my_list:
                unique = unique + " " + w

    return unique
    
df["C"] = df["C"].apply(uniqueList)
```

Version2

```
sentences = df["B"] .to_list()
for s in sentences:
    s_split = s.split(' ')  # keep original sentence split by ' '
    s_split_without_comma = [i.strip(',') for i in s_split]
    # method 1: re
    compare_words = re.split(' |-', s)
    # method 2: itertools
    compare_words = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([i.split('-') for i in s_split]))
    method 3: DIY
    compare_words = []
    for i in s_split:
        compare_words += i.split('-')

    # strip ','
    compare_words_without_comma = [i.strip(',') for i in compare_words]

    start to compare
    need_removed_index = []
    for word in compare_words_without_comma:
        matched_indexes = []
        for idx, w in enumerate(s_split_without_comma):
            if word.lower() in w.lower().split('-'):
                matched_indexes.append(idx)
        if len(matched_indexes) > 1:  # has_duplicates
            need_removed_index += matched_indexes[1:]
    need_removed_index = list(set(need_removed_index))

    # keep remain and join with ' '
    print(" ".join([i for idx, i in enumerate(s_split) if idx not in need_removed_index]))
    # print(sentences)

print(sentences)
```

None of this are working properly as is not the best way to approach.

Comment: What is your question? What about you edit the question and add everything you tried and what are the problems you're having here.

Comment: this looks like a homework question, where is your own effort?

Comment: @Umar.H I have actually tried one workaround on this, concatenating and removing duplicates which worked but for some scenarios not all duplicate words need to be removed, same for integers and other specific words.

Comment: can you post the code as well ?

Comment: @Umar.H sure, done. There's a third also try but I can't post more code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using regular expressions, assuming that `df` is the name of the dataframe.

So the idea is simple, if B has something in A, replace it with B's value. Else return string B + A.

```py
import re

def create_c(row):
    if re.sub(row['B'], row['B'], row['A'], flags=re.IGNORECASE) == row['A']:
        return row['B'] + ' ' + row['A']
    return re.sub(row['B'], row['B'], row['A'], flags=re.IGNORECASE)


df['C'] = df.apply(create_c, axis=1)
```

**Edit #1**: I forgot to add the `return` keyword before the re.sub() statement.

Here's running the code in the shell:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = [['tshirt for women', 'TSHIRT'], ['Zaino Estensibile', 'SJ Gang']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])
>>> df
                   A        B
0   tshirt for women   TSHIRT
1  Zaino Estensibile  SJ Gang
>>> 
>>>
>>> import re
>>> def create_c(row):
...     if re.sub(row['B'], row['B'], row['A'], flags=re.IGNORECASE) == row['A']:
...         return row['B'] + ' ' + row['A']
...     return re.sub(row['B'], row['B'], row['A'], flags=re.IGNORECASE)
... 
>>> 
>>> df['C'] = df.apply(create_c, axis=1)
>>> df
                   A        B                          C
0   tshirt for women   TSHIRT           TSHIRT for women
1  Zaino Estensibile  SJ Gang  SJ Gang Zaino Estensibile
>>>
```

Comment: thank you but does not bring the values in column C

Comment: and it is also creating duplicates for lower/upper situations

Comment: @Isa, I have edited the answer, I forgot to write the return keyword.

Comment: thank you so much, is the best version I had with one exception, it creates duplicates in situations like value from column A: L'OCCITANE - OLIO DOCCIA, balue in B: L´Occitane, results having in C: L´Occitane L'OCCITANE - OLIO DOCCIA. Is there anything I could add to avoid this? Again, thank you so much for all your effort

Comment: @Isa It is becase `´` character is different in `L´Occitane` and `L'OCCITANE`. What should be done about that?

Comment: because one is in proper and other in upper I guess. It should remain only the value in upper from column B

Comment: No, that's not the case. ```>>> s = "L´Occitane"
>>> s.upper()
'L´OCCITANE'
>>> s = s.upper()
>>> s.lower()
'l´occitane'``` Both lowercase and uppercase have the same `´`. You should probably clean your data first and then create the new column. Also, please upvote if this answer helps.

Comment: it helps but excepting the character, it still creates duplicates as for Lovable in col A and LOVABLE in column B where outputs LOVABLE Lovable

Comment: It seems to be working on my end. ```>>> data = [['Lovable', 'LOVABLE']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])
>>> df['C'] = df.apply(create_c, axis=1)
>>> df
         A        B        C
0  Lovable  LOVABLE  LOVABLE
```

Answer (score 2):

Using sets, get strings in `A` not in `B`.Put these strings in column `C`as a set

```
  df['C'] = [(set(a).difference(b)) for a, b in zip(df['A'].str.upper().str.split('\s'), df['B'].str.upper().str.split('\s'))]
```

Strip of the new column `C` the set brackets and the comma and `concatenate` with column `B` if B is a substring of A. If not, just concatenate B and A.

Code below;

```
df['C']= np.where([a in b for a, b in zip(df.B.str.lower(),df.A.str.lower())], df['B'] + ' ' + df['C'].str.join(',').str.replace(',',' ').str.lower(), df['B'] + ' ' + df['A'])
```

print(df)

Output

```
               A          B                          C
0   tshirt for women     TSHIRT           TSHIRT for women
1  Zaino Estensibile    SJ Gang  SJ Gang Zaino Estensibile
2     Air Optix plus  AIR OPTIX             AIR OPTIX plus
```

Comment: thank you but I can't convert to lower and remove all the commas. I apologize, I should have mentioned, all it should remain the same, including occurrence

Comment: Look at the output. it does work. The conversion to lower etc etc is just a transformational method and does not impact original dataframe. It is a means to an end